# Use Perl to accumulate one CSV column for each unique ID

Tags: perl, csv

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
1.0,25,some_value,01
1.0,25,some_value,01
1.0,10,some_value,02
1.0,10,some_value,02
1.0,3,some_value,03
1.0,3,some_value,03
```

I am accumulating the value of the second column 
into the scalar `$sum` with this Perl program:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $sum = 0;
my $i = 0;
my @cols;

while (my $line = <STDIN>) {
  chomp $line;
  push @cols, [ split ",", $line ];
  $sum += $cols[$i][1];
  $i++;
}

print "$sum\n";
```

This will get the sum `76` which is the sum of all the values in column two.

If you refer back to the CSV file above, the last column represents an ID. What I really need is to get the sum of column two for each ID in the last column, column four. The sum of column two for ID `01` would be 50, ID `02` would be 20 and ID `03` would be 6.

I'm not sure where to begin to make this happen, or if it can be worked into my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code puts the whole of the input into array `@cols`. When all you need is the sum of one column that is a huge waste of memory.

Your program can be written

```
my $sum;
while (my $line = <STDIN>) {
  my @fields = split /,/, $line;
  $sum += $fields[1];
}
```

This is easily modified to categorize the sums by using a hash. This code uses the last field as a key to identify the hash element that should be incremented by the value of the second field.

```
my %sums;
while (my $line = <DATA>) {
  chomp $line;
  my @fields = split /,/, $line;
  $sums{$fields[-1]} += $fields[1];
}

use Data::Dump;
dd \%sums;
```

**output**

```
{ "01" => 50, "02" => 20, "03" => 6 }
```

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is use a hash to store the sum for each unique id:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %sum; # key: the unique id, value: the sum
while (my $line = <STDIN>) {
    chomp $line;
    my @cols = split /,/, $line;
    $sum{$cols[3]} += $cols[1];

}

for (sort { $a <=> $b } keys %sum) {
    print "$_: $sum{$_}\n";
}
```

This will print:

```
01: 50
02: 20
03: 6
```

Comment: You shouldn't use a literal string for the first parameter to `split`. It is processed as a regular expression except in the one special case where it is a string containing a single space.

Comment: You are correct. This is what happens when I copy the code from OP :)